# jQuery Validation plugin: prompt for override

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, validation

I have a jQuery form that has validation of a sort.  It is a data entry screen with two text boxes on it.  Each text box has a aloud value of 1 to infinity, but a 'desired' range of 36-84 for the first control and 50-300 for the second. If the value is within the desired range, then the submit is to go through.  If the range is outside the desired, but within the aloud, say 25 for either, then the user need to be prompted AFTER they press submit.  If they say yes to the prompt, the submit goes through, if they say no, it does not.

Thanks to the help of Cooper Maruyama, I have gotten to the point of trying to actually implement the answer in ASP.Net world.  The issue is that the text box id's are determined at run time and are passed in to the initialize function in a ids object.

When I run it, I get the following errors: *Unable to get value of the property 'settings': object is null or undefined*

Here is my code:

```
var manageResidentWeightsJs = {

    initialize: function (ids) {

        var cbDeclined = $(ids.cbDeclined);
        var cbIsOutOfFac = $(ids.cbIsOutOfFac);

        $('<div id=errorSummary>The following values fall out side of the normal range:</div>')
                .append('<ul id="errorsList"></ul>').hide().insertAfter(ids.formView);

        var txtHeight = $(ids.txtHeight);
        var txtWeight = $(ids.txtWeight);

        function confirmation() {
            var x;
            var r = confirm("Are you sure?");
            if (r == true) { return true; }
            else { return false; }
        }

        $(ids.formView).validate({
            invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
                if (confirmation()) { form.submit(); }
            }
        });

        txtHeight.each(function (index, elem) { $(elem).rules("add", { min: 0 }) });
        txtWeight.each(function (index, elem) { $(elem).rules("add", { min: 0 }) });
    }
}
```

The follow code is being used to call the above code.  In this code the ASP.Net has been replaced with the '#' as to eliminate the ASP.Net factor from the problem:)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ids = {
      formView: '#mainForm',
      txtHeight: '#heightCtrl',
      txtWeight: '#weightCtrl'
    };

    manageResidentWeightsJs.initialize(ids);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell the validator that an 'undesired' range is 'invalid'. then use the invalidHandler to show a confirmation box. if they hit ok, force the form to submit anyways.

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FqX6h/14/

You'll have to edit the validation rules to your liking.

HTML:

```
 <form id="form" action="">
    <input type="text" name="some_name" value="" id="some_name" minlength="5">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="required" size="10" onclick="">
  </form>
```

js:

```
       function confirmation() {
            var r=confirm("Are you sure?");
            if (r==true) {return true;}
            else {return false;}
        }
        $(function() {
            $("#form").validate({
                rules: {
                    some_name: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
                    if (confirmation()) {form.submit();}
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I am sorry, but it does not answer the question:(  I am going to clarify in my example above.

Comment: The main issue I have with your example is that it is NOT using the jQuery validation framework.  An idea I just had:  Can I wire up to the onclick of the sumbit, independently from the validation which would get called AFTER the validation says that it is OK to submit?  That way the desired value is only checked AFTER the system makes sure the value is aloud.

Comment: Looks good, but...  I am using ASP.Net MVC and can not statically put in the id of the input controls.  The id's are being passed into the initialize, so I believe I need to add the rules to the controls after calling the validate function on the form, but when I do that, I get a "Unable to get value of the property 'settings': object is null or undefined" error.  Will edit above to reflect my actual code.

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately I don't know much about ASP.net MVC. This should at least answer your js question (and give you a skeleton to work with).

Comment: Please forgive me, I had not actually run or tried to run your jsfiddle example.  It does not seem to work for me.  That being the case, I am having a hard time accepting that it is the answer to the js piece of the pie.  As far as the ASP.Net, I will add more to the question to clarify that part, it isn't really an ASP.Net issue...

Comment: i forgot to update the jsfiddle link, my bad. check it now. if it submits, it'll redirect you to google with the field values appended. otherwise, you should see a message that says 'you clicked cancel'